# re.match is not working as I expect in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Link to the problem is:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-credit-card-number/problem

Regexp is working fine in online regex tester but not working perfectly when I am using re.match() of python.
For following condition this regular expression is not working:-
**It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits.**

```
import re
test_case=int(input())
for _ in range(test_case):
    print('Valid' if re.match("^(?!.*(\d)(-?\1){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$",input()) is not None else "Invalid")
```

For example:- 5133-3367-8912-3456 
In this case its giving **"No matches"** in online regex tester. But in case of python3 with **re.match**, it's returning match object
re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='5133-3367-8912-3456'

So for this test case of the above mentioned hackerrank problem,this is printing "Valid" in place of "Invalid".

Comment: Making it a raw string seems to work: `r"^(?!.*(\d)(-?\1){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$"`

Comment: If you want your string to be `\d` the source code string in python has to be `"\\d"`.

Comment: Use ‘\\d‘ or r’\d’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @snakecharmerb said, some of the backslashes get interpreted in double quotes.

```
import re
a = r"^(?!.*(\d)(-?\1){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$"
b = "^(?!.*(\d)(-?\1){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$"
print(a)
print(b)

test_case = "5133-3367-8912-3456"
print('Valid' if re.match(a,test_case) is not None else "Invalid")
print('Valid' if re.match(b,test_case) is not None else "Invalid")
```

output

```
^(?!.*(\d)(-?\1){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$
^(?!.*(\d)(-?){3})[456]{1}\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$
Invalid
Valid
```

Comment: It's not so much the double quotes - Python is not Bash - as the absence of the `"r"` prefix on the string :-)

Comment: By printing the string representations of the regexes you are showing that `"\1"` is not being interpreted as a group reference, and hence the unexpected behaviour.